# How to set datetime optional parameter in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How to set datetime optional parameter in sql server stored procedure?

Below is my stored procedure, I want to set `@LocalDateTime = utcdate` when `@LocalDateTime is null`.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[ABC] 
(  
    @LocalDateTime datetime=getutcdate()
)
```

Comment: does it do anything? If so, what? And why is that not what you need?
Or in other words: please ask your question so people understand what you need help with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value of the parameter must be a constant. You can set it inside the body of the stored procedure:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[ABC] 
(  
    @LocalDateTime datetime = null
) 

as

begin

    set @LocalDateTime = ISNULL(@LocalDateTime,GETUTCDATE())

end
```

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) on MSDN. Here is an excerpt:

> *default* 
> A default value for a parameter. If a default value is defined
>   for a parameter, the procedure can be executed without specifying a
>   value for that parameter. **The default value must be a constant** or it
>   can be NULL.

Comment: thanks @Andrea, actually I wanted to assign value on declaration but I think that is not possible..